in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS I use the german keybord but I can write get any of the special chrarcters like @ which I can print with the english keyboard
in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS I use the German keyboard but I can write get any of the special characters like @ which I can print with the English keyboard.

please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. Your question makes no sense.
